# Clojure agents interaction failure

Tags: clojure, agent

Imagine: flat world n*n cells. There are moving objects. They can collide, and according to process one of them should be destroyed.

I am using the ideas from ant colony of Rich Hickey to represent objects as agents. So after collision one of agent must stop his work after receiving message from other agent.

There is a code  snippet to illustrate my problem: second agent stops unexpectedly.

```
;agents
(def f_guy (agent nil))

(def s_guy (agent nil))

;functions for agents
(defn f_do [x]
  (do
    (Thread/sleep 20)
    (println "f")
    (send-off *agent* f_do)))

(defn s_do [x]
  (do
    (Thread/sleep 40)
    (println "s")
    (send-off f_guy nil)
    (send-off *agent* s_do)))

;the process
(defn start []
  (do
    (send-off f_guy f_do)
    (send-off s_guy s_do)))

;go
(start)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sent `f_guy` a request to call `nil` as a function. He did, and that got him into a broken state by throwing an exception. Then, you ask him to call `nil` again. But he can't even agree to do that, because he is broken and waiting for someone to fix him. So `s_guy` is hanging around waiting for `f_guy` to acknowledge (not necessarily perform, yet) the request, and `f_guy` has clocked out for the day.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to (send-off f_guy nil) twice and it has shown me **java.lang.RuntimeException**.

Answer (score 1):

May I ask what are you trying to accomplish here?

Both the first and the second agent fail in my experiments which is because you are basically putting agents inside agents inside agents...

Example:

```
(def a (agent 0))
(send-off a inc) ; -> #<Agent@29de03: 1>
```

So by doing this:

```
(defn f_do [x]
  (do
    ...
    (send-off *agent* f_do)))
```

You are recursively returning agents inside agents.

Comment: I will try to explain. Like in Rich Hickey's ant colony I have a 2d world and moving objects in it. I want to evluate collisions and as soon as objects are represented as agents - to *kill* object I have to stop an agent, and I do it by sending him nil-message.

Comment: The ant-colony demo is *very* old (like three years). Having agents send themselves actions to simulate recurring actions is not the best solution.

Really you shouldn't be representing object "as agents", but rather use agents (or something else) to manage the changing states of your objects. Instead of sending an agent `nil` (which, really, makes him crash and burn, and is very "rude" to him), you need a better model for how you coordinate state between various objects.